# Using Ruby safe operator with greater than

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to use Ruby's safe operator in the following scenario:

```
if attribute_value && attribute_value.length > 255
```

The following does not work if the attribute_value is nil:

```
if attribute_value&.length > 255

# NoMethodError: undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

I get why, but what I'd like to know is how to I get round this. The following works, but it's ugly as hell:

```
if attribute_value&.(length > 255)
```

What's the recommended way of doing this? I guess I could do the following:

```
if attribute_value&.length.to_i > 255
```

That's not so bad for this situation. Anything else?

Comment: "The following works" - does it though? Try with a non-nil.

Comment: You must use the `&` again in the result of `attribute_value&.length`, since `>=` is also a method being invoked in an object (`nil&.length&.>= 1`)

Comment: I personally would go with your first line. It's short and dead simple. I could be persuaded to tolerate the `attribute_value&.length.to_i`, temporarily (if we need to deploy a hotfix _right now_ and this is the only concern with the pull request)

Comment: @SebastianPalma: oh my. Something something back to perl roots :) (this how I imagine perl code looks like, unreadable mess of random sigils)

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPalma for showing how to make it work.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev for advising to go with the simple solution. That's what I will do. It's easier to read and look at.

Comment: Yes @SergioTulentsev, I personally would take a time to avoid chaining `&`'s and `try`'s. But is how you say, temporarily tolerable if a hotfix is needed.

Comment: You could write `attribute_value.length > 255 unless attribute_value.nil?`, which returns `nil` if `attribute_value #=> nil`.

Comment: `class NilClass; def length; -Float::INFINITY; end; end`. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @CarySwoveland then why not simply `class NilClass; Comparable.instance_methods.each { |m| next if m == :==; define_method(m) {|*| false} }; end`? Also `attribute_value.length > 255 unless attribute_value.nil?` seems better as `attribute_value.length > 255 if attribute_value` since `false` has no length either. Although `.respond_to?(:length)` would be more correct

Answer (score 11):

As a direct answer to the question asked, you can use the safe navigation operator directly since `x > y` is really just calling the `>` [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3E) on the object x. That is, `x > y` is the same as `x.>(y)` or `x.send(:>, y)`

Therefore, you can use `x&.> y`. Or, in your situation, `attribute_value&.length&.> 255`

Personally, I'd prefer `attribute_value && attribute_value.length > 255`, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: I return to this answer about three times a year. It's still the best one. 

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing depends on what kind of missing values you're trying to accommodate and if failing to define it is the same as being within bounds, or outside of.

Your approach of:

```
attribute_value&.length.to_i > 255
```

Seems reasonable enough so long as `nil` means "not outside of bounds".

Often I handle this with guard conditions like:

```
return unless attribute_value

if attribute_value.length > 255
  # ... Handle condition
end
```